# How can I check AMD GPU power usage in Windows cmd?

Tags: windows, command-line, amd-gpu

For NVIDIA GPUs, I use

```
nvidia-smi -i 0 --format=csv,noheader --query-gpu=power.draw
```

and this command prints (for example) `150.00 W` to stdout.

But how can I get AMD GPU power usage from Windows command line?

Comment: Is there a `amd-smi`? This question is maybe also more on-topic at [Super User](//superuser.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software like Overdrive5 for Windows may help you I hope.
[Overdrive5 Github](https://github.com/BackupGGCode/overdrive5)